# Почему java компилятор пропускает i = -+-+-+i и в то же время не пропускает i = */*/i?

Tags: java, int

```
int i = 1;
i = -+-+-+i;
System.out.println(i);
```

Компилиуруется, выводит **-1**; Если минусов будет четное число - будет **1**.
Если так писать компилятор, то можно разрешить и что-то вроде `i=*/*/;`- но такое не компилируется.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**Вопросы:** для чего разработчики java оставили такую возможность? Чтобы кандидаты на собеседовании сыпались или чтобы код стал более не понятным? Или для более благородных целей? И почему тогда не сделали возможность `*/*/` воткнуть? Есть ли у данной возможности какое-то научно-техническое название?

Comment: а что ожидалось при выполнении `i=*/*/` ?

Comment: Квадрат и корень разумеется.

Comment: что за квадрат и корень?

Comment: Да я говорю о том, что всё что угодно. Оставлена какая-то баговая функциональность, которая юзерам явно не нужно. То что один минус - = -1*i - это правильно, а то, что -+-+-+ пропускает - это совершенно глупо.

Comment: Это не глупо, так как является синтаксически и семантически верным выражением, если тяжело разобрать что происходит, просто добавь скобки и станет понятнее. Остальные твои примеры не являются синтаксически корректными.

Comment: @Grundy я вполне умею извлекать код из .class; Я вполне вижу, что код выше эквивалентен (после оптимизации компилятором) `int i = 1;
        int i = -(-(-i));`  Я просто с разрабами не согласен и пытаюсь понять их логику, но пока логики в оставлении этой функции не вижу. Только чтобы на собеседовании чудаки на букву "м" тебя тролили.

Comment: @AndrewKachalin  i=*/*/ - так нельзя, потому что это закрывающий тэг многострочного комментария /*........*/

Comment: @Виктор Тут согласен с вами, почему-то сразу не подумал об этом.

Comment: @Andrew Kachalin посмотри на ютубе Александр Маторин — Неадекватное Java-интервью. там много похожего

Answer (score -1):

Ха, просто - и + это унарные операции, а * и / - бинарные операции, требуют двух операндов и поэтому */*/i даёт ошибку. Никаких странностей тут нет. Не знаю, правда, зачем в Яве унарный плюс?

О, нашёл где-то: "унарный плюс " + " – не выполняет никаких действий над числом или выражением".

Ответы:

1. **Для чего разработчики java оставили такую возможность?** - Очевидно, операция "унарный минус" является востребованной, хотя её можно и заменить на  "0 - операнд". Это как ++ или --. Про "унарный плюс" - кто знает?
2. **Чтобы кандидаты на собеседовании сыпались или чтобы код стал более не понятным?** Чтобы сыпались - да.
3. **Или для более благородных целей?** - Нет.
4. **И почему тогда не сделали возможность */*/ воткнуть?** - Я бы предложил "унарное деление" как альтернативу 1/операнд. С умножением сложнее, это как плюс.
5. **Есть ли у данной возможности какое-то научно-техническое название?** - Унарные и бинарные операции.

Comment: Есть принцип наименьшего удивления и его суть в том, чтобы меньше оставлять у программы удивления от юзера.

Comment: А мы-то тут как удивляемся! :-)